# create matrix using 2 dataframe columns, while multiplying two others

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach

I hope you can help me with a problem that had me stuck for a while now.

I have a dataframe with a few million rows, that looks like this: df

```
 id       V1=i     count.i      V2=j      count.j  
  1      10000      1          A          1
  2      20000      1          B          .33
  2      20000      1          C          .33
  2      20000      1          D          .33
  3      19482      1          E          1
  4      10000      .5         A          1                   
  4      20000      .5         A          1
  5      34556      1          E          1
  6      10101      1          A          .5
  6      10101      1          B          .5
  7      20000     .5          E          .5
  7      20000     .5          F          .5
  7      44044     .5          E          .5
  7      44044     .5          F          .5
```

- I would like to turn this into a matrix (preferably sparse) that looks like this:

matrix

```
                 A,     B,     C,     D,     E,     F,     G,     ,...,  J
     10000      1.5     x      x      x      x       x     x 
     10101       .5     .5     x      x      x       x     x 
     19482       x      x      x      x      1       x     x 
     20000       0.5   .33   .33    .33     .25     .25   x  
     34556       x      x      x      x      1       x     x 
     44044       x      x      x      x      x       x     x      
     ,.., I
```

- V1 are ordinal classes that make up the rows, V2 are ordinal classes that make up the columns. In this example, 49 possibilities exist.
- where the value in each respective cell is the sum of count.i * count.j for that observations i-j.
- the duplicates in id mean a duplicate in V1 and/or V2, which is all needed information. I wan't to weight my measurements using count.i and count.j by multiplication. E.g. with id=7, 4 of the possibilities have occured, which are 20000-E, 20000-F, 44044-E & 44044-F, giving them weight 0.25 each in the total sum.
- I tried the foreach function. however, can't get it to work

Help would be greatly apreciated!

*edit: I have changed the example to be more clear and representative*

Comment: You mean V1$1 to V1$7 and V2$A to V2$F? Also provide the code you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
data<-read.table(textConnection(
"id       V1     count.i      V2      count.j  
1      10000      1          A          1
2      20000      1          B          .33
2      20000      1          C          .33
2      20000      1          D          .33
3      19482      1          E          1
4      22222      1          F          .5
4      22222      1          G          .5
5      34556      1          E          1
6      10101      1          A          .5
6      10101      1          B          .5
7      20000     .5          B          .5
7      20000     .5          F          .5
7      44044     .5          E          .5
7      44044     .5          F          .5"
), header=TRUE)
```

---

```
  require(tidyverse)
  data %>% mutate(ij=count.i*count.j) %>% 
  select(-count.i,-count.j) %>%
  dcast(id+V1~V2,value.var="ij") %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

> ```
>         V1   A    B    C    D    E    F   G
> [1,] 10000 1.0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA
> [2,] 20000  NA 0.33 0.33 0.33   NA   NA  NA
> [3,] 19482  NA   NA   NA   NA 1.00   NA  NA
> [4,] 22222  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.50 0.5
> [5,] 34556  NA   NA   NA   NA 1.00   NA  NA
> [6,] 10101 0.5 0.50   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA
> [7,] 20000  NA 0.25   NA   NA   NA 0.25  NA
> [8,] 44044  NA   NA   NA   NA 0.25 0.25  NA
> ```

Adapted to your new explanation.